# Connect/disconnect "Managed Metadata Service" to the user profile service

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, user-profile-service

In my SharePoint 2013 Farm, I have Two Managed Metadata Services

- "Managed Metadata Service 1" and
- "Managed Metadata Service 2".

Right now User profile service is connected to "Managed Metadata Service 1", but I want to disconnect it from "Managed Metadata Service 1" and want to connect it to "Managed Metadata Service 2".

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change the Connection by following these steps:

1.Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators group.

2.On the Central Administration website, click Application Management.

3.On the Application Management page, in the Service Applications section, click Configure service application associations.

4.On the Service Application Associations page, in the View list, click Service Applications.

5.In the Web Application/Service Application column, click the User Profile service application for which you want to edit the connection.

6.In the Configure Service Application Associations dialog box, Switch to Custom, and select the Managed Metadata Service check box as you want.

Source:[enter link description here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487294.aspx)